# get the name of the clicked menu item

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

Is there any way to get the name of the clicked menu item?
I have created a new add-in file with menus and sub-menus. Can I get the name of the sub-menu which I clicked to be used inside the macro?

For example:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Dim NewControl As CommandBarPopup
Dim mItem, SubMenu
On Error Resume Next
Call Auto_Close

Set NewControl = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, temporary:=True)
NewControl.Caption = "&Menu"

Set mItem = NewControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With mItem
    .Caption = "Sub-Menu1"
    .OnAction = "submenu1"
End With

Set mItem = NewControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With mItem
    .Caption = "Sub-Menu2"
    .OnAction = "submenu2"
End With

Set mItem = NewControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With mItem
    .Caption = "Sub-Menu3"
    .OnAction = "submenu3"
End With

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

So the above code creates an Add-In ribbon with button "Menu" and sub-Menus "Sub-Menu1, Sub-Menu2 and Sub-Menu3".

If I click any of the sub menus I need a message  box displaying the name of the menu I clicked.

Comment: Menus? What Excel version are you using? There have not been menus since XL 2003. From 2007 onwards there's the ribbon. You need to provide A LOT more detail.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: So, where is the menu? - Oh, and did you read the part about providing more detail. A LOT more detail?

Answer (score 0):

The ActionControl property of the Commandbars object will tell you which menu item was clicked to call your code.

```
Dim ctl As CommandBarControl

Set ctl = Application.Commandbars.ActionControl
```